# Passing plot labels through a function with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function which renders a plot - how can I pass the plots label information (e.g., plot title, axis titles, etc.) through a function as I'm trying to do below?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_func <- function(sample_size, lab_list) {
  mtcars %>% 
    sample_n(sample_size) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(lab_list)
}

plot_func(sample_size = 5, lab_list = list(title = "Plot Title", x = "MPG", y = "HP"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `purrr::invoke` or `do.call`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
plot_func <- function(sample_size, lab_list) {
 mtcars %>% 
   sample_n(sample_size) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
   geom_point() +
   do.call(labs, lab_list)
 }
```

-testing

```
plot_func(sample_size = 5, lab_list = list(title = "Plot Title",
      x = "MPG", y = "HP"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. There does seem to be a bug in `labs()`. According to the documentation it should accept a list, but that does not appear to be the case in practice. These are different

```
labs(x="HELLO")
# $x
# [1] "HELLO"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "labels"

labs(list(x="HELLO"))
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$x
# [1] "HELLO"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "labels"
```

The latter has an extra list that's getting in the way. You can use the base function `do.call` to property inject parmeters from a function into a list

```
do.call("labs", list(x="HELLO"))
# $x
# [1] "HELLO"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "labels"
```

So your function would be

```
plot_func <- function(sample_size, lab_list) {
  mtcars %>% 
    sample_n(sample_size) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    do.call("labs", lab_list)
}
```

It looks like there as a [commit on Jan 4](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/c70ef2a670c0e0fd061f9298a472d41872b0768a#diff-033fa02a53370d55ada591f0cde9b8a7b93a7cffa8707a9c757931e8ebe24bbb) that will allow you to use `!!!` in future (yet unreleased at the time of this question) versions of ggplot. So hopefully soon you'll be able to do

```
plot_func <- function(sample_size, lab_list) {
  mtcars %>% 
    sample_n(sample_size) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(!!!lab_list)
}
```

which is more consistent with how the rest of the tidyverse functions work.